# How to do selection in PostgreSQL with join when more than one row satisfies requirements?

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

How to do selection to get JSON array in one cell when doing INNER JOIN when there are more than 1 values to join?

ex Tables:

T1:

```
id | name
1    Tom
2    Dom
```

T2:

```
user_id | product
1         Milk
2         Cookies
2         Banana
```

Naturally I do `SELECT * FROM T1 INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.id = T2.user_id`.
But then I get:

```
id | Name | product
1   Tom     Milk
2   Dom     Cookies
2   Dom     Banana
```

But I want to get:

```
id | Name | product
1   Tom     [{"product":"Milk}]
2   Dom     [{"product":"Cookies"}, {"product":"Banana"}]
```

If I do something with `agg` functions, then I need to put everything else in `GROUP BY`, where I have at least 10 arguments. And whole query takes more than 5 minutes.

My `T1` is around 4000 rows and `T2` around 300 000 rows, each associated with some row in `T1`.

Is there a better way?

Comment: `array_agg()`? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [LATERAL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL) you can solve it as given example below:

```
-- The query
SELECT  *
FROM    table1 t1,
LATERAL (   SELECT  jsonb_agg(
                        jsonb_build_object( 'product', product )
                    )
            FROM    table2
            WHERE   user_id = t1.id
        ) t2( product );

-- Result
 id | name |                     product
----+------+-------------------------------------------------
  1 | Tom  | [{"product": "Milk"}]
  2 | Dom  | [{"product": "Cookies"}, {"product": "Banana"}]
(2 rows)


-- Test data
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table1 (
    id      int,
    "name"  text
);

INSERT INTO table1
VALUES  ( 1, 'Tom' ),
        ( 2, 'Dom' );

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table2 (
    user_id     int,
    product     text
);

INSERT INTO table2
VALUES  ( 1, 'Milk' ),
        ( 2, 'Cookies' ),
        ( 2, 'Banana' );
```